# Get data from remote API on Vue.JS app load

Tags: vue.js, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm working on hybrid mobile app using (for the first time) vue-router. All custom modules and router navigation working great but when I need to get the data from remote API on app load I don't find the right way to do it. I'm stuck on that point.

This is the 'store.js' file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        profile: {}
    },
    mutations: {

    },
    actions: {
        appInit() {
            axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/junihh')
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    }
})
```

I try to load the data with Axios but nothing printed to the console. How to load the data on app load properly?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you call `appInit` action?

Comment: That is why I'm stuck, I don't know the way to call that action on app load. Sorry. :-(

Comment: In the spec you pass to `new Vue`, you should defined a [`created()` hook](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks). Call your action from there.